# Use custom tab bar with QMdiArea

Tags: c++, qt, tabs, qt4, qmdiarea

I see that `QMdiArea` has a tabbed view mode. I want to be able to split the main window with two `QMdiArea` widgets and to be able to drag and drop tabs between each of them.

I have already done it with a simple `QTabWidget` where I can set custom tab bar. At the same time I want to switch `QMdiArea` view mode thus using `QTabWidget` is not an option for me. But I don't see any methods to set custom tab bar within `QMdiArea`.

How can this be done?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289344/how-to-treat-an-old-question-which-had-an-answer-edited-into-it

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Answer provided by [Dmitry K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818356/dmitry-k)</sup>

---

You have to make a new class inheriting `QMdiArea`. Set its view mode to `TabbedView` to make the standard `QTabBar` to be constructed within `QMdiArea`. Then get all children and find `QTabBar` widget with `QString(QObject::metaObject()->className()) == "QTabBar"`. Hide it. You will get a blank area above the document in `TabbedView` mode. Construct you custom tab bar and reparent it to your custom mdi area. Connect signals and slots that are fired and used when the sub windows and tabs are activated. You can have your custom tab bar as a class member of your custom mdi area.

Code example:

1. Looking for a standart `QTabBar` within a custom mdi area in its constructor:

   ```
    m_pMdiAreaTabBar = NULL;
    m_pMdiArea->setViewMode(QMdiArea::TabbedView);
    QObjectList listChildren = m_pMdiArea->children();
    for (QObjectList::Iterator i = listChildren.begin(); i != listChildren.end(); ++i)
    {
    if (QString((*i)->metaObject()->className()) == "QTabBar")
    {
    m_pMdiAreaTabBar = dynamic_cast<QTabBar*>(*i);
    break;
    }
    }
   ```
2. Reparent:

   ```
    m_pTabBar->setParent(m_pMdiArea);
   ```
3. Hiding:

   ```
    if (m_pMdiAreaTabBar != 0) m_pMdiAreaTabBar->hide();
   ```
4. Signals & Slots used: `QMdiArea::subWindowActivated(QMdiSubWindow*)`, `QTabBar::currentChanged(int)`